# Is there a way to set a default highlight?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I'm setting up a dashboard that will let a fruit supplier see their share of wallet for different fruit vendors, and for different categories of fruit (melons, berries, etc.), as well as the fruit and the packaging it's sold in.

I want share of wallet to always show up as an opaque section of the three bar charts on the right, like in the After screenshot. But it's inconvenient to always have to go to the chart on the left and click "Our sales". Is there a way to set a default legend selection, conditional formatting, or something similar, so that something similar to the After screenshot will always show up?

[Before clicking on the "Our sales" legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zJta.png)

[After clicking on the "Our sales" legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Phv.png)

I put the share of wallet in the tooltip but that shows the number but I want the visual

Comment: Short answer, no, not possible. Closest would be a default page slicer, but that would be crossfilter, not highlight of course.

Comment: You could click the chart then add a bookmark. Then reset the charts and add another bookmark. Then assign those bookmarks to buttons..